# Увеличить картинку при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Помогите решить проблему, я создал сайт с картинками, которые берутся от сайта Unsplash, сделал, что хотел, но я бы еще хотел, чтобы была возможность при нажатии любой картинки, будто с рандома или с поиска, она увеличивалась, я много вариантов переискал, как это сделать, но у меня не получалось, но я нашел один вариант, который мне очень понравился и я хотел бы, чтобы у меня примерно также было https://playcode.io/916548, надеюсь кто-то поможет.

```js
const requestURL = 'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=1&per_page=20&client_id=Dn8-42Jk1UNg4-nIQbG_xlewlntyxqNTU2laqw9yWCs';
const randomImages = 'https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?client_id=Dn8-42Jk1UNg4-nIQbG_xlewlntyxqNTU2laqw9yWCs&count=100';
const searchImages = document.querySelector('form');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const images = document.querySelector('.images');


function searchStart() {
  images.innerHTML = '';
  input.value = '';
}

fetch(randomImages)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data) {
      data.forEach(item => {
        images.innerHTML += showRandomImages(item)
      });
    }
  })

function showRandomImages(data) {
  return `
        <div class="data">
            <img src='${data.urls.regular}'>
            <a href='${data.links.html}' target='_blank' class='link'>${data.description ? data.description : ''}</a>
            <a href='${data.links.html}' target='_blank' class='user'>Photo by: ${data.user.name ? data.user.name : ''}</a>
        </div>
    `
}

function search(searchImg) {
  let url = `${requestURL}&query=${searchImg}`;
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      return result.results;
    });
}

function showImages(data) {
  images.innerHTML = '';
  data.forEach(item => {
    let image = document.createElement('div');
    image.className = 'showImage';
    image.innerHTML = `
        <img src='${item.urls.regular}'>
        <a href='${item.links.html}' target='_blank' class='link'>${item.description ? item.description : ''}</a>
        <a href='${item.links.html}' target='_blank' class='user'>Photo by: ${item.user.name ? item.user.name : ''}</a>
        `
    images.appendChild(image);

  });
}

searchImages.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  // if (input.value === '') {
  //     alertify.error('Enter the title!')
  // } 
  event.preventDefault();
  let searchImg = input.value;
  searchStart();
  search(searchImg)
    .then(showImages)
});
```

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #111;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  letter-spacing: -.1rem;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  width: 570px;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #212121;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 320px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.input-task input {
  width: 425px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input-task {
  width: 500px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.button,
button[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #E55D87 0%, #5FC3E4 51%, #E55D87 100%);
  margin: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  background-size: 200% auto;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.button,
button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-position: right center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  padding: 4px 14px 42px 4px;
  margin-left: 34px;
}

.data {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.data a {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

.showImage {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.showImage a {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}

.link {
  left: 45px;
  top: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.user {
  left: 45px;
  bottom: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.images {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/02f0ec4094.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify/css/alertify.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify/css/themes/default.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="alertify/css/themes/adaptive_default.min.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Unsplash Images</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Unsplash Images Gallery</h1>
  <form>
    <div class="input-task">
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search image..." autocomplete="on">
    </div>
    <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
  <div class="images">
  </div>
  <!-- <script src="alertify/js/alertify.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>  -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Просто при создании HTML-а картинки выбирайте `:last-child` элемент и прослушивайте событие клика, а там уже со стилизацией сами выбирайте, либо делайте на весь экран либо просто увеличиваете используя `transform: scale(1.5);`, а сам размер уже сам корректируйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюст дальше вы сами справитесь

```js
const images = document.querySelector('.images');
for (elem of images.children) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let posX = e.target.offsetLeft;
    let posY = e.target.offsetTop;
    let w = e.target.offsetWidth;
    let h = e.target.offsetHeight;
    let tempImg = e.target.cloneNode();

    let newImg = document.createElement('div');
    newImg.className = 'image-scope';
    newImg.append(tempImg);
    newImg.style.left = posY + 'px';
    newImg.style.top = posX + 'px';
    newImg.style.width = w + 'px';
    newImg.style.height = h + 'px';

    document.querySelector('body').append(newImg);

    setTimeout(() => {
      newImg.classList.add('image-scope-active');
      newImg.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
      })
    }, 250);
  })
}
```

```css
.data {
  width: 320px;
  height: 320px;
}

.data>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-scope {
  position: fixed;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.image-scope img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  padding: 12px;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.image-scope-active {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}

.image-scope-active img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 75%;
  max-height: 75%;
}

.image-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <div class="data">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1239&q=80" alt="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Просто Miha, извините, я не очень понял, пытался разобраться. Если, Вам, не сложно, у вас есть время, могли бы, Вы, этот ваш кусок кода, вставить в мой код, чтобы я понял, как оно должно работать правильно?

Comment: Если сначала открыть картинку, а потом снова попытаться её открыть (Не закрывая текущую), то тогда код ломается.

Comment: @ΝNL993, Это вы про его пример или вообще? Мне необязательно, чтобы прям код такой был, мне просто главное, чтобы была возможность по клику увеличивать, а следующий клик, допустим на крестик в исходное состояние возвращать, мне просто анимации с того примера понравились

Comment: @АндрейХотюн я про пример [@ПростоMiha](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/374508/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-miha), спокойно копируйте CSS, "анимация" не такая уж тяжёлая.

Comment: @ΝNL993 а именно js код?

Comment: В js коде просто выбирается позиция и добавляется событие клика, ничего сверхъестественного, но если лень писать самому, копируйте, всё-таки площадка то свободная.